# Logically split a large string into suitable substrings

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, substring

I have a very large string of (English) sentences that I need to split into several smaller strings that will populate smaller fields (e.g. 100 characters).

I'd like to do this logically, and add an indicator to denote that the string will be continued (In my case "[cont.]").

By 'logically', I mean I'd like to split the string by sentence, then by individual word, and finally, by character (Where a word may be 100+ characters long, this would need splitting across multiple fields).

What is the most efficient way of doing this in C#? Should I split by sentence and then deal with each sentence individually, or is there a better way?

My current code just splits by sentence, and works like this:

```
        const string splitIndicator = " [cont]";
        var splitLength = maximumLengthOfField - splitIndicator.Length;            

        var sentences = Regex.Split(workText, @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+");

        var line = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var sentence in sentences)
        {
            if (line.Length + sentence.Length >= splitLength)
            {
                yield return line + splitIndicator;
                line = new StringBuilder();
            }
            line.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", line.Length > 0 ? " " : "", sentence);
        }
        yield return line.ToString();
```

Comment: Thre is a question of *trade off*: what's better - allow, parts of sizes `3, 99` but split on *full stop* `'.'` or, say, `50, 52` split by *space* `' '`? Usually, we detect possible splits, compute *penalty function* on each and chose the one with the minimum penalty